# Differential and Maximum

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

Have any theorem to solve this problem? 
$\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\big(\text{max}(x-25e^{-0.06},0))$

Answer (score 0):

It‘s not everywhere differentiable. You have a linear function until the left part hits zero with slope one.